# Jbehave : Given for entire story

Tags: bdd, jbehave, scenarios

I was wonder if it possible to execute entire story as given steps for verification.

I mean :

```
Story 1 
Given ..
When ..
Then ..


Story 2
Given ...
When ...
Then Story1 passed
```

Any way to achieve this scenario ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to run a test by using just "Given" annotations?

Comment: I was meaning to reuse entire story as a postcondition. I know that it's possible to execute a story as a precondition by using "given stories" but I not sure how to execute it as a post condition ...